# A network-related or instance-specific error occured

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition successfully. I have 2 problems

1. `Its showing 2 (local) servers in server name`
2. `A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Name Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed  as a  default instance   then local  will work  else named instance  you have to connect by servername and  instance name .  you can browse for  instance name in connect to window pop up too. 
Check  your sql configuration wizard weather sql service is running.

Comment: how to find sql service is running or not?

Comment: in windows search box search for sql server configuration manager  and then check for sql server services

Comment: "There are not items to show in this view" thats the message shown when I click on SQL Server Services.

Comment: It  means  you have installed only Connecting tools , not the database engine services. reinstall

Answer (score 11):

Run services.msc

Start all services for SQL server including SQLEXPRESS it will work

Thanks,

Comment: Is this in the Windows cmd?

Comment: Win+R button will open Run window.Type services.msc.

You can also type directly in Windows cmd

Answer (score 2):

Go to Start >> Select All Programs >> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 >> Configuration Tools >> SQL Server Configuration Manager

Then open SQL Server Configuration Manager >> Select SQL Server Services >> Select SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) and check the status of SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) whether is it running or not

If SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) Status is in Running it’s ok, otherwise right click on SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) and click Start

Now restart your SQL Server Management Studio and check it I hope it will work for you.